# RDP prompting for user/password with saved credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, mstsc

Connecting to a Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server from Windows 10.

In the past, I simply had to double-click my .rdp file and I was connected and logged-in automatically.

Now, no matter what settings I try in mstsc.exe, the server prompts me at least for the password.  (If I check "Always ask for credentials", it brings me to a screen that lets me select the User)

If I change the "Computer" field of MSTSC.exe, the "Always ask for credentials" checkbox changes to "Allow me to save credentials".

What can I do to diagnose this issue and get auto-login working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this, to the same server version, from the same OS Version.

Start with a blank RDP session, and enter the Server name. If there are saved credentials, remove them by clicking 'Delete'.

[image]

The view should change to be similar to the below
[image: RDP setup page]

Ensure 'Allow me to save credentials' is ticked.

Save the Connection to somewhere you can access, and then click 'Connect'

Enter the correct password :-

[image: Credentials Box]

Click ok. Logout of RDP Session. Double click your RDP again, and it should log in.

If it doesn't it's possible there is a Group Policy preventing the use of saved passwords.

Comment: Please see my edit above regarding the "Allow me to save credentials" checkbox.  For some reason, with this particular IP, the text of that checkbox changes.  Weird.

Comment: It does that if credentials are already saved. You can try attempt to delete them and create them again. If it's still requiring them at the system logon screen, the ability to use saved credentials has been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the hostname/ip and credentials as key from PowerShell using the command :

```
cmdkey /generic:<ip or hostname> /user:<username> /pass:<password>
```

For viewing your saved keys
*Note: The saved **password will not be visible** in any case.*:

```
cmdkey /list
```

For deleting a key:

```
cmdkey /delete:<hostname>
```

This works for running a RDP session from command prompt as well as the RDP client.

Hope this helps.

For more details you can visit the [Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(v=ws.11).aspx)